# How do I mark pip-installed dependencies as satisfied?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to get ROS Hydro to run on Arch Linux, which uses Python 3 by default, and pacman for package management.

I've fixed a few Python 2/3 issues with rosdep, rospkg, etc, which I installed via pip.  I've reached the step of running rosdep for the catkin workspace. My command is:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y
```

This gives me a bunch of errors like:

```
rqt_publisher: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS [arch]
rqt_top: No definition of [python-psutil] for OS [arch]
pcl_ros: No definition of [libpcl-all] for OS [arch]
rosclean: No definition of [python-rospkg] for OS [arch]
smach_ros: No definition of [python-rosdep] for OS [arch]
...
```

Looking at the arch dependencies, there doesn't appear to be some packages defined for Arch:
github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml

Since I didn't install using pacman (which is set up as the Arch package manager), what's the best way to tell rosdep that I've satisfied dependencies with pip?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108816/how-do-i-mark-pip-installed-dependencies-as-satisfied?/) by [spease](https://answers.ros.org/users/9736/spease/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the `--skip-keys` option

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0